# Using ember-cli addon

Tags: ember-cli-addons

I am trying to do a simple thing : 
use addons in the default project created with the command

```
ember new myproject
```

The initial project does compile: I can see the welcoming message on localhost:4200. Any addon I choose to add is installed the same way:

```
ember install theAddon
```

I can see the newly added addon in the package.json file. I have read that on build process ember will scan the dependencies (listed in package.json) and will create class instances for dependency which has the **ember-addon** keyword listed in their dependency file.  So if I understand this correctly it is done automatically. Well when I run I always get

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: A helper named 'my-addon' could not
>   be found.

For example one that  I tried is

```
ember-radio-button
```

and it complains that it cannot find 'radio-button' helper

Comment: Did you get a `Installed addon package.` message after running `ember install ember-radio-button`? I just tried this addon in a fresh project and got no errors when using `{{radio-button}}` in a template. It sounds like the addon wasn't installed correctly.

Comment: I re-installed ember and create a new project and added the addon, Exactly what I did the first time and it worked. I have no idea why it did not work the first time

Answer (score 0):

When installing an addon you need to **restart** the ember server. Installing an addon modifies the build environment.

After killing the server and restarting with `ember s` or `ember server` the addon can be used safely.